# how to set-up /tf_static?

Tags: navigation, tf-broadcaster, tf2, tf-static, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I’m setting up the move_base on our robot to allow autonomous navigation.

In order to publish the static transform between base_laser and base_link and reduce the load on the “communication” link, I want to use the tf_static topic of tf2 instead of the tf:broadcaster. I don’t understand how to do that. Could you help me?

Is it possible for move_base to use transform publish on tf_static topic?

Best regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207366/how-to-set-up-/tf_static-?/) by [julienH](https://answers.ros.org/users/22204/julienh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I usually use this command in a launchfile :

```
<launch>
      <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" 
            name="my_tf" args="0 0 1 3.14 0 1.57 /map /my_tf 30"/>
</launch>
```

the args are the translation for the 3 first arguments and the angles ( in Radian in an Euler form ) for the 3 last ones.

I hope this will help you

---

Originally posted by [scarlett](https://answers.ros.org/users/12086/scarlett/) with karma: 170 on 2015-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1